# How to create a vs-code task to deploy WAR file on tomcat extension?

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I'm migrating from Eclipse to VS-Code and I'm trying to make the deploy process quickly. I want to create a vs-code task to deploy WAR files.
I'm using the command **adashen.vscode-tomcat:tomcat.war.run** but it doesn't seen to work.

I'm using Tomcat for Visual Studio Code extension v.0.11.1.

My tasks.json look like this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gradlew clean build",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Deploy",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "adashen.vscode-tomcat:tomcat.war.run",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}\\build\\libs\\SMEWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"]
        }
    ]
}
```

After execute getting the follow erro:

> > Executing task in folder SMEWeb: adashen.vscode-tomcat:tomcat.war.run
> >     C:\WorkspaceGit\sme\SMEWeb\build\libs\SMEWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war <
>
> The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>
> The terminal process command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /c
>   adashen.vscode-tomcat:tomcat.war.run
>   C:\WorkspaceGit\sme\SMEWeb\build\libs\SMEWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war'
>   failed to launch (exit code: 1)
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Does any one have a clue?
Thanks

Comment: if you don't use task,could you deploy successfully?

Comment: Yes, I have to go to the generated WAR file, right-click and "Run on Tomcat Server".

Comment: have you try to `cd` to the generated war file,then depoy the .war  in  task `command` ?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt work. Even a simple command to start tomcat without args ("command": "adashen.vscode-tomcat:tomcat.server.start")  returning the same error..

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [source code](https://github.com/adashen/vscode-tomcat/blob/3b1c628aaf559ef2639f616211be60914d321f4f/src/Tomcat/TomcatController.ts#L181), i think it could work if the method accepted the file path as a String or if you manage to pass the 'vscode.Uri' object as a parameter to the 'tomcat.war.run' command.

This was the best i could came up for the entire process, but you still have to pick the .war manually every time you run this task:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "compile",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "mvn compile",
            "problemMatcher": []  
        },
        {
            "label": "package",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "mvn package",
            "dependsOn": ["compile"],
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Run WAR",
            "command": "${input:runWar}",
            "dependsOn": ["package"],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "runWar",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "tomcat.war.run"
//          ,"args": { DOESNT WORK =/
//              "uri" : {"fsPath" : "${workspaceFolder}/target/ROOT.war"}
//          }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could look something like this.

```
    {
        "label": "Run",
        "command": "${command:tomcat.war.run}",
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
```

After a good bit of searching for my own use, I got help from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57470981/4588923

I have not yet found a way to supply the .war file as an argument and it work.

And althought the call works from tasks.json, I think the main issue is the extension does not support doing such. Perhaps a feature request is in order.

Comment: Agree, actually I give up VS Code for doing Back End stuffs and return for my Eclipse.

Comment: I returned to Netbeans for hot swapping code, debugging and deploying to Tomcat. It's 2021 and VSCode's tomcat extension is just not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

RedHat has developed a VSCode extension that helps with configuring and deploying a tomcat server within VSCode.  Seems a lot better then others I have tried.

[VSCode Blog Post](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tomcat-jetty)

[Community Server Connection VSCode Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-community-server-connector)

Comment: redhat server extension supports apache tomcat 9, & eclipse jetty 9: both of bygone era