# How can I run a VSCode command as a task

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode on Github has an issue titled `Running commands as tasks #11396`.  It involves running a VSCode command as an internal task in VSCode.

alexr00 commented on `Dec 20, 2018 that`:

`You can now have commands in tasks.json` and points to the following docs:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_settings-command-variables-and-input-variables

I've read through these docs and I am still unable to figure out how to do what I want.   For starters, I'd like to create a simple task that runs the liveserver extention start code: extention.liveServer.goOnline

Anyone have any thoughts on what to try or where to look?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

So for instance you could do this:

```json
    {
      "label": "run copyLinesDown command",
      //  "type": "shell",
      
      "command": "${command:editor.action.copyLinesDownAction}",

      // "command": "${command:extension.gist.open}"  // etc

      // "runOptions": {
      //   "runOn": "folderOpen"
      // }
    },
```

That is a task in `tasks.json`.  When you run that task, the current line in the active editor will be copied down.

So I presume if you used

```json
    "command": "${command:extension.liveServer.goOnline}",
```

in a task like the above that extension command should be run.  (Check the spelling, is it `extention` or `extension`?)

See specifically [command variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_command-variables).

And then you can assign a keybinding to that task with (in keybindings.json):

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+h",            // binding of your choice
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
        "args": "run copyLinesDown command"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I kept trying to find a "type" for the command.  It never occurred to me to just leave that out.  Your example worked perfectly.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to recognize commands from add-ons such as: command:extention.liveServer.goOnline

Comment: Hmm, that is why I tried it with `extension.gist.open` a command from an installed extension and it worked just fine.  It seems to work with/without the `shell`/`process` type for me.  Did you try both versions with your command?  It might need `process` for example.

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot.  I misspelled  "extension",  thank you Mark :)